# How to refer the resources from a third library in xml file?

Tags: android, xml

Now I add a third library to my android project, it contains some resources that defined the strings, drawables, colors, etc. I want to refer some resources from the third library in my Project xml files. Many wasy has been tried, not work. Any help that can give me some point would be appreciated.

For example, refer a string like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="5"
        android:text="@string/date_heading"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/MessageHeaderDetailsHeadingStyle" />
```

The string "date_heading" is already defined in a third library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path to that resource for example `com.example.project.date_heading` where the `com.example.project` is the package name of the library.